# FileOutputStream - Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: java, windows, fileoutputstream

I'm using the following code to write files to the disk.

```
`try{
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;            
     fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
     fileOutputStream.write(fileData);
     fileOutputStream.flush();
 }
 finally{
     fileOutputStream.close();
 }
      `
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error intermittently:

> Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

I have already checked a few cases when this problem can happen, like the lack of **Paged Pool Memory**, but none of them is my case. I'm using windows server 2003 Server R2 SP2. Architecture x86.

Should I try to write the file in smaller chunks? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Is your disk full? is your file too big and your file system is FAT32?

Comment: My disk is not full, the biggest file is about 20MB and the file system is NTFS.

Comment: Are you on Windows XP?

Comment: I'm using windows server 2003 Server R2 SP2. Architecture x86

Comment: I am not sure what kind of control you have on this machine, but you can try this guide: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/solved-insufficient-system-resources-593357.html

Comment: "Biggest file" so multiple files. Are you writing multiple files in parallel? How much files are we talking about?

Comment: Yes, this is a web application that can writte files in parallel. I'm writting abou 5k files a day. Not many in parallel (about 5).

Comment: "about 5" sounds like you have no actual rate limiting functionality that makes sure you dont exceed that amount. I suggest you find (by experimenting) the number of parallel writes you can do without problems, and limit your parallel writes to <50% of that. (e.g. with a fixed sized threadpool)

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

First, you should consider using buffers. Try wrapping your FileOutputStream with a BufferedOutputStream.

```
try{
     BufferedOutputStream outputBuffer = null;            
     outputBuffer = new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream(filePath));
     outputBuffer.write(fileData);
     outputBuffer.flush();
 }
 finally{
     outputBuffer.close();
 }
```

Second, try checking if you really are running out of handles. I left a comment with a link regarding this.

Comment: Thank you r3st0r3. Does the BufferedOutputStream divide the file in smaller chunks before saving? What cand I do if the java process is consuming too many handles?

Comment: When you use a BufferedOutputStream, your calls for IO go through a buffer, so not each FileOutput will create a new IO handle, a native file handle in this case.
I don't think your java process is consuming too many handles, it could be a misbehaving driver though. Java is pretty stable that way, and it will take some time for you to run out of handles if the issue purely emanates out of your code. How long before you are seeing this on running your app?

Comment: I use this tool to check for open handles. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655 
If the piece of code you are writing is inside a loop, this can be an issue.